# How should I send concurrent data?

Tags: vhdl

I have a design of 16 different signals of 16 bits vectors, these are displayed on a LCD. One signal may look like "FFFF" where 4 bits represent one hex character. I send data to the LCD through a serial interface. Now the problem, each of these 16 signals could possible change at the same time how do I account for this in my design.

Comment: Going to need some more details about what you are trying to achieve. Are all 16 signals displayed at once on the LCD or does the LCD only display one of the signals at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the problem down.

First deal with capturing the 16 x 16 = 256 bits.  If these are synchronous to some common clock, then you are OK, otherwise you need to use an anti-metastability latch on each signal, a minimum of two latches per signal. (512 latches).

Now all your signals are latched on the same clock, so creating a shift register to shift out the bits in any particular pattern is simple.

You need to ensure that the data being shifted never changes at the same time as the first clock, either double buffer the data or use a much faster clock.